# How to randomize a math function/operator in visual basic (console)

Tags: vb.net, console-application, operator-keyword, basic

This is my code so far

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Randomize()

    Dim number1 As Integer
    Dim number2 As Integer
    Dim answer As Integer
    Dim userAnswer As Integer
    Dim name As String


    Console.WriteLine("Hello! Welcome to your Maths Quiz! Please enter your name >")
    name = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Nice to meet you " + name + ". Lets start the quiz")

    Randomize()
    number1 = Rnd() * 11 + 1
    number2 = Rnd() * 11 + 1
    answer = number1 + number2


    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            Console.WriteLine("What is " & number1 & " + " & number2 & " = ?")
            userAnswer = Console.ReadLine
            If userAnswer = answer Then
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, the answer was " & answer)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As InvalidCastException
        Console.WriteLine("Oops you have typed in a number, please start over")
    End Try

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
End Module
```

I need to create a random function to take place of the "+" sign and i have tried many ways but the output comes up weird, i was wondering if you can help, Thanks

Comment: Show us something you've tried and then we can help you fix or improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for + - * / then I would do this, if only + - and could go with IIF statments

Create a new random variable operator

```
op = Int(Rnd() * 4) '0+ 1- 2* 3/
```

Calculate the anwser with a function

```
answer= calc(number1, number2, op)

Function calc(n1, n2, op)
    If op = 0 Then calc = n1 + n2
    If op = 1 Then calc = n1 - n2
    If op = 2 Then calc = n1 * n2
    If op = 3 Then calc = n1 / n2
End Function
```

And 1 more function to get the operator sign

```
Console.WriteLine("What is " & number1 & s_op(op) & number2 & " = ?")

Function s_op(op)
    If op = 0 Then s_op = "+"
    If op = 1 Then s_op = "-"
    If op = 2 Then s_op = "*"
    If op = 3 Then s_op = "/"
End Function
```